# Change dash Checklist values by callback

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I would like to change the selected options of an plotly dash checklist by an callback. My minimal working example is as following (Values should change by hitting the 'load' button -> at loading the page nothing ist selected, after click the button 'SF' should be selected):

```
import dash

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([

    dcc.Checklist(
    options=[
        {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
        {'label': 'Montréal', 'value': 'MTL'},
        {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
    ],
    labelStyle={'display': 'block'},
    value=[]
    ),  

    html.Button('load', id='load-button', n_clicks=0)
])

@app.callback(Output('checkliste', 'value'),
              Input('load-button', 'n_clicks'))
def change_values(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks > 1:
        return ['SF']



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Plotly Dash homepage has a lot of great resources - check this out: https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks.

Scroll down to the section titled "Dash App With Chained Callbacks" and you will find almost exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm not shure wheater the thing you mentioned is the way to solve my problem (or maybe I didn't get the point!) but the thing is that the [example](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks) handles with radio buttons and not with checklist. So my question is how to give more than one value back that should be checked?

Answer (score 0):

There were some little mistakes that cause the problem I want to mention here:

- There is no id for the dcc.Checklist in the code
- There must be a return statement. In my case, there was no return defined
- if `n_clicks < 1` means the button must be clicked twice for something to happen. It should be `n_clicks > 0`

So the solution is:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Checklist(
            id="checklist",
            options=[
                {"label": "New York City", "value": "NYC"},
                {"label": "Montréal", "value": "MTL"},
                {"label": "San Francisco", "value": "SF"},
            ],
            labelStyle={"display": "block"},
            value=[],
        ),
        html.Button("load", id="load-button", n_clicks=0),
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output("checklist", "value"), Input("load-button", "n_clicks"))
def change_values(n_clicks):
    return ["SF"] if n_clicks > 0 else []
```

Thanks to **AnnMarieW** to find the mistakes on [plotly forum](https://community.plotly.com/)!
See the [original post](https://community.plotly.com/t/change-dash-checklist-values-by-callback/53254) on the forum.